# Count iterations performed on enumerable object

Tags: ruby

I need to select from an array the elements that satisfy some condition, and count the number of iterations it took. For example:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5...1,000,000]
count = 0
array.keep_if { |x| x % 2 == 0 }
```

I want to increase the counter every time the condition `x % 2 == 0` is satisfied. Is there a way to tell how many iterations took place?

Comment: Technically this is not counting iterations, it is counting the subset of true conditions when iterating. The number of iterations will be in this case the size of your array, because `.keep_if` cannot optimise away the check for any element of the array, and will simply check each one in turn.

Comment: Please tell us more on why you need this. If you store the value, then just do a `size` afterwards. If not, just use the `count` function istead of keep_if. Are you doing some multi threading here or why do you need this?

Comment: You are confusing two things: the number of times the condition was satisfied and the number of times the condition was evaluated. It cannot be told whether a condition is satisfied unless it is evaluated. The number of times it is evaluated is the number of the elements in the original array.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work as expected.

```
array.keep_if { |x|
    keep = (x % 2 == 0 ? true : false)
    count = count + 1 if keep
    keep
}
```

Comment: It would be more idiomatic to use a guard close "next unless (x % 2).blank?"

Comment: Sure but the block has to return a boolean value iirc.

Comment: @alediaferia `next` might return a result: `next false unless (x % 2).blank?`. BTW, `next unless` is ok since it returns _falsey_.

Comment: @mudasobwa I knew `next` might return a result, though I didn't now this works also for the `next unless` case. Awesome! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, whether you won’t call `Array#size` on result:

```
array.reduce([0, []]) { |memo, el| 
  next memo unless el % 2 == 0
  memo[0] += 1
  memo.last << el
  memo 
}
#⇒ [
#  [0] 500,
#  [1] [ ... ] # the filtered result
#]
```

Comment: Because he wants to count the iterations not the results.

Answer (score 0):

I would chose a simpler solution. The `count` you seek will be equivalent with the length of the resulting array. So you can use a classic `select` method and then count the results.

```
array = (1..1000000).to_a
[res = array.select {|x| x % 2 == 0}, count = res.length]
```

puts the reduced array to res, and the number of true conditions on count